# smbclient connect from Linux to Windows Directory

Tags: linux, samba, libsmbclient

I need to connect from Linux to Windows to copy some files.
My Windows directory looks like this:
\Server\Pucblic\dir\offline\etc
I tried:
    smbclient -U user%pw \Server\Public\dir\offline\etc
Also

```
smbclient -U user%pw \\Server\Public --directory dir\offline\etc
```

nothing worked.

But When i try connecting to \Server\Public - that ist working...

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

**Note:** Try to use front slash as below.

```
smbclient -U user%pw //Server/Public --directory dir/offline/etc
```

If you want to copy files from single command line try :

```
smbclient -U user%pw //Server/Public --directory dir/offline/etc -c 'put "yourfilename"'
```